# Defining a command that distinguishes between greek and roman letters?

Tags: fonts, macros, conditionals, greek

I'm using pdftex and I want to define a command for the typesetting of quantum mechanical operators that produces upright letters with a `\hat` accent. The problem is that the obvious solution

```
\newcommand*{\op}[1]{{\hat{\mathrm{#1}}}}
```

does only work for roman letters but I also use at least one operator that should be represented by a greek letter for which the \mathrm command produces rubbish output. So it would be nice to define a command that distinguishes between greek and roman letters via an if statement. Since I have very little experience with TeX I don't really know how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you strictly use one token in the argument of `\op`, here is a way:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\op}[1]{\hat{\ifcat#1\relax#1\else\mathrm{#1}\fi}}
```

The command is robust because it would break if used in captions. Use it only as

```
\op{A} \op{x} \op{\Gamma} \op{\beta}
```

You might consider also to add `\mathop`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\op}[1]{%
  \mathop{\hat{\ifcat#1\relax#1\else\mathrm{#1}\fi}}\nolimits}
```

that will provide correct spacing of the symbol used as an operator.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you very much. This really solves my problem. I go with the first alternative since the `\mathop` command produces wrong output, when used with indices such as `\op{H}_{i}`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a key command.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry if I dig out this old post, but: Would it be the same if I wrote `\ifcat#1a\mathrm{#1}\else#1\fi` instead?

Comment: @campa Yes, that's the same